# camelcase en VS Code

Tags: python, importación

No es un error porque si me funciona al final la importacion del camelcase pero me arroja como un mensaje de advertencia supongo el VS Code.

En la linea del from **camelcase** import CamelCase, el camelcase en negrita me marca con una linea amarrilla. En la imagen adjunta esta el mensaje que me arroja.

Sera que me pueden ayudar para que no siga saliendo en amarillo por favor.

Hice la importación correcta, lo verifique con el pip list y me aparece el camelcase en la lista.

Muchas gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: muchas veces me pasa cuando estoy en un entorno virtual, si ejecutas el código y no te da error de importación entonces todo está bien y simplemente VSCode no ha reconocido el módulo descargado aún.

Comment: Christian, gracias por tu comentario. Voy a tenerlo en cuenta cuando reinicie el VS Code.